# Check if even one value differs in a Php array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I have an array of seller ids
for ex :

```
Sellers ( [0] => 1 [1] => 10 )
```

If incase there were many sellers like hundreds, how do I check if there's (atleast 2) different sellers in the array ?
Basically I can't have 2 different seller ids in that array.
and if thats the case it should print  :
"More than 1 seller".

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `array_count_values(array $array);` function for this

```
$Sellers = array(10, 10, 10);
$SellersCount = array_count_values($Sellers);
if(count($SellersCount) > 1) {
  echo("More than 1 seller");
}
```

Comment: I am getting "array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!" with this.

Comment: nvm got it working with : $SellersCount = array_replace($Sellers,array_fill_keys(array_keys($Sellers, null),''));